# Setting Content-Type header to application/x-www-form-urlencoded using apollo-datasource-rest library

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, graphql, apollo

Has anyone had trouble setting a `Content-Type` header using `apollo-datasource-rest`? I’m trying to encode for `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and my REST API is still not seeing the params:

```
class AuthAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  ...

  willSendRequest( request ) {
    request.headers.set( 'X-API-KEY', this.apiKey )
    request.headers.set( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    console.log( request.headers )
    console.log( request.body )
  }

  async getToken( params ) {
    return this
      .post( apiEndpoints.auth.token, params )
      .catch( err => handleError( err ))
  }
}
```

Output:

```
// console.log( request.headers )
Headers {
  [Symbol(map)]: [Object: null prototype] {
    'X-API-KEY': [ '1234567890...' ],
    'Content-Type': [ 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' ]
  }
}

// console.log( request.body )
{
  identifier: 'my.name@domain.com',
  format: 'json',
  secret: 'P@55w0rd'
}
```

It appears the request (POST) body is formatted correctly and that the headers are set correctly. Using the same credentials and headers via postman returns a successful result, but not via this library for some reason:

```
// response
{ success: 0,
  error:
    { status: 400,
      message: 'Missing username or password',
      code: 117
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

It's maybe a little bit late but i had the same problem before. You need to put the params as query string if you want to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, for example

```
class AuthAPI extends RESTDataSource {
  ...

  willSendRequest( request ) {
    request.headers.set( 'X-API-KEY', this.apiKey )
    console.log( request.headers )
    console.log( request.body )
  }

  async getToken( params ) {
    return this
      .post(
          apiEndpoints.auth.token,
          'loginId=myloginId&password=12345678',
           {
              headers: {
                 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
              },
           }
      )
      .catch( err => handleError( err ))
  }
}
```

Not a good one but it's should works

Comment: Thank you. I had my query params set as an object and couldn't figure out why things weren't working. 

One correction to your code solution: you don't need to set the Content-Type header both in willSendRequest and in this.post.

Comment: I think you have to show your code for us to help you. Yea thank you for the correction!

Comment: this solution is works for me too.